# Hide the "Download OpenAPI specification" button

Tags: fastapi, redocly

I'm using FastAPI and I want the /redoc page to not display the Download button.

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kW8h4.png)

**I know that users will still be able to download the specification, but I need to hide this button.**

FastApi automatically generates /redoc, how can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

So, there is an [option in redoc to hide the download button](https://github.com/Redocly/redoc#redoc-options-object), we just have to get it in from FastAPI. There doesn't really seem to be any way to pass configuration into Redoc from FastAPI. However, what you can do is [override the static files themselves](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/extending-openapi/#serve-the-static-files), so by copying the [`get_redoc_html` function from `fastapi.openapi.docs`](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/dd4e78ca7b09abdf0d4646fe4697316c021a8b2e/fastapi/openapi/docs.py#L75C6-L75C6), we can make the small modification of `<redoc spec-url="{openapi_url}">` to `<redoc spec-url="{openapi_url}" hide-download-button>`, adding the `hide-download-button` attribute.

All in all the code becomes

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse

app = FastAPI(redoc_url=None)


def get_custom_redoc_html(
    *,
    openapi_url: str,
    title: str,
    redoc_js_url: str = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/redoc@next/bundles/redoc.standalone.js",
    redoc_favicon_url: str = "https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/img/favicon.png",
    with_google_fonts: bool = True,
) -> HTMLResponse:
    html = f"""
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>{title}</title>
    <!-- needed for adaptive design -->
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    """
    if with_google_fonts:
        html += """
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,700|Roboto:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    """
    html += f"""
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{redoc_favicon_url}">
    <!--
    ReDoc doesn't change outer page styles
    -->
    <style>
      body {{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <noscript>
        ReDoc requires Javascript to function. Please enable it to browse the documentation.
    </noscript>
    <redoc spec-url="{openapi_url}" hide-download-button></redoc>
    <script src="{redoc_js_url}"> </script>
    </body>
    </html>
    """
    return HTMLResponse(html)


@app.get("/redoc", include_in_schema=False)
async def redoc_try_it_out() -> HTMLResponse:
    return get_custom_redoc_html(openapi_url=app.openapi_url, title=app.title)
```

Comment: Thank you, you literally saved me! You are a god!